# What are some good beginners resources for learning MSBuild?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm looking for resources for learning MS Build (not just books).  At this point I'm mostly concerned with merging assemblies and automating build tasks. (nightly builds etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good tutorial on MSBuild scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326445/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-msbuild-scripts)

Answer (score 2):

Neither merging nor automating builds has a lot to do with MSBuild.  You'd need ILMerge and, say, CruiseControl.NET.

Comment: so I'm barking up the wrong tree?  What does MSBuild provide then?

Comment: I'd say you'll need a fair knowledge of msbuild if you want to automate ILmerging and get the most out of automated builds.

Comment: I said not JUST books, I'm including e-books, articles, and webcasts.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the online docs?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use the docs previously mentioned, but they weren't really helpful to learn MSBuild.  For that, I turned to ["Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286).  After reading it and learning all the MSBuild concepts, I now use the MSBuild doc's as a reference.  They finally make sense.