# Run code through external application before compiling in visual studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have a project that needs some of the code to be dynamically edited before the project is compiled. Is there some way that I can instruct Visual Studio to send the code through some external program and then read from it's output for what to compile? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a C# project.

Comment: You could possibly think of a better way other than passing the codes to an external program. That's not a good practice and cause error in compilation.

Answer (score 3):

If your pre-compile task is relatively simple you should be able to add a "Pre-build task" through the Build Events tab of the Project->Properties dialog
[as described on this MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks(v=vs.100).aspx) More likely you'll want to use msbuild.exe to build your project outside of the IDE; tutorials for msbuild are discussed in [this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326445/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-msbuild-scripts)